# same cv function (opencv) in the c++

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I've encountered to cvUpdateMotionHistory function in the OpenCV. after searches, I understand that this function developed for C language and equivalent function at the C++ is update_mhi. In OpenCV 3 release, cvUpdateMotionHistory function don't work correctly but update_mhi function work correctly. Now, I want to understand the equivalent function's:
cvCalcMotionGradient
cvSegmentMotion
cvCalcGlobalOrientation

what's the equivalent function's?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work correctly"? Does the code compile and gives wrong output or doesn't even compile? According to the opencv documentation, it should work.

Comment: calcMotionGradient and segmentMotion and calcGlobalOrientation are mentioned in https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/optflow/samples/motempl.cpp probsbly in namespace cv:: give it a try.

Comment: 1. These functions don't exist in the cv namespace.

Comment: 2. These functions don't even compile.

Comment: i linked the code, probably you can find the namespaces and includes there on your own. No time, sorry. e.g. using namespace cv::motempl;
right in the beginning of the linked github code.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the OpenCV functions are not only under the `cv` namespace, but under the module namespace.

[Here you can see](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d2/d84/group__optflow.html) that the documentation of OpenCV refers to this function as:

> cv::motempl::calcGlobalOrientation

If you are using (which I do not recommend) :

```
using namespace cv;
```

then you need to call the function with `motempl::calcGlobalOrientation` if not call it with `cv::motempl::calcGlobalOrientation`

Don't forget to include:

```
#include "opencv2/optflow.hpp"
```

for some examples take a look to [the link given by Micka](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/optflow/samples/motempl.cpp).